# Google Cloud acceso SSH

Tags: ftp, servidor, ssh, google-cloud-platform

Tengo un servidor en **Google Cloud** y utilizaba el accesos **SSH** para editar, instalar y cambiar archivos. El problema es que estaba buscando una manera de instalar un acceso **FTP** y utilicé: *apt-get install vsftpd libpam-pwdfile*
y cambié el archivo *vsftpd.conf* que esta ubicado en */etc/vsftpd.conf*.

Después del cambio perdí todo el acceso al servidor con **SSH** y ya no puedo deshacer lo que hice.

¿Como puedo solucionar el problema ?
¿Como puedo crear un acceso **FTP** sin joder el acceso **SSH** ?

Intente seguir este tutorial:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216385/how-to-create-ftp-vsftpd-in-google-cloud-compute-engine

Comment: Mira que estás haciendo dos preguntas en una y te podrían cerrar la pregunta como demasiado amplia

Comment: Ya probaste `gcloud compute config-ssh --remove` y luego `gcloud compute config-ssh` como indica en https://serverfault.com/a/876311 y https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar restablecer la máquina en el menú de Compute Engine > VM instances, seleccionar tu máquina y luego ejecutar restart o reset. Antes creando un respaldo de tu disco.

O quizás puedas acceder seleccionando opción de conectarse por ssh en el panel de instancias. O probar con otra de las opciones listadas en el menú. Por ejemplo, con

```
gcloud compute --project "tu proyecto" ssh --zone "tu zona" "el nombre de tu instancia"
```

Esta cadena se genera cuando presionas la opción de `view gcloud command` en el menú desplegable en la columna de "Connect" en la instancia que selecciones.

Una vez que corras ese comando, te pedirá que te autentiques con tu correo asociado al proyecto y luego podrás correr eso con tu cloud sdk y te correrá a través de PUTTY.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es para ver si puedes volver a entrar por `ssh`. Si ya puedes entrar, puedes utilizar `sftp` para conectarte a esa instancia.

```
sftp usuario@host
```